# how to avoid the unchecked call warning in java for a java.util.HashMap

Tags: java, json

I am storing an image as a string and converting it to a JSONObject and storing it in a json file and at last i'm reading from the same json file and retrieving the string as an image.In this process i get an warning

> Simple.java:29: warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to put(K,V) as a member of the raw type java.util.HashMap
>          fjson.put("imagestring",base64String);
>                  ^
>   1 warning
>   the code is:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.FileReader;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

public class Simple 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        JSONParser jsonParser=new JSONParser();
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new ByteArrayOutputStream(1000);
        BufferedImage img=ImageIO.read(new File("/root/Desktop","Screenshot.png"));
        ImageIO.write(img, "png", baos);
        baos.flush();
        //to store the image as a string
        String base64String=DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(baos.toByteArray());
        baos.close();
        System.out.println("string"+base64String);
        JSONObject fjson=new JSONObject();
        fjson.put("imagestring",base64String);
        //the string is written into a json file
        try
        {
            FileWriter writer=new FileWriter("/root/project/code/json/res.json");
            writer.write(fjson.toString());
            writer.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //reading from a json file
        try
        {
            FileReader fr=new FileReader("/root/project/code/json/res.json");
            try
            {
                JSONObject jParse=(JSONObject)jsonParser.parse(fr);
                String jsonString=(String)jParse.get("imagestring");
                byte[] bytearray =DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(jsonString); 
                BufferedImage imag=ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytearray));
                ImageIO.write(imag, "png", new File("/root/project/code/json","snap3.png"));
            }
            catch(ParseException e)
                    {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                    }
        }
        catch(IOException e)
                {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't as `JSONObject` use raw types: `public class JSONObject extends HashMap implements Map, JSONAware, JSONStreamAware{`

Comment: You probably want a better JSON API than org.json to do JSON creation; Jackson, for instance.

Comment: you can use generic type of JSONObject if it's available